# Trying to set up Pandas Crosstabs and Running into issues with loops

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I am new to python and cannot work out why this loop will not run-

I can run this-

```
df1 = pd.crosstab(df['Gender: What gender do you identify with?'], df[Banner[0]], normalize= 'columns')
df2 = pd.crosstab(df['Gender: What gender do you identify with?'], df[Banner[1]], normalize= 'columns')
df3 = pd.crosstab(df['Gender: What gender do you identify with?'], df[Banner[2]], normalize= 'columns')
df4 = pd.crosstab(df['Gender: What gender do you identify with?'], df[Banner[3]], normalize= 'columns')
df5 = pd.crosstab(df['Gender: What gender do you identify with?'], df[Banner[4]], normalize= 'columns')
df6 = pd.crosstab(df['Gender: What gender do you identify with?'], df[Banner[5]], normalize= 'columns')
df7 = pd.crosstab(df['Gender: What gender do you identify with?'], df[Banner[6]], normalize= 'columns')
df8 = pd.crosstab(df['Gender: What gender do you identify with?'], df[Banner[7]], normalize= 'columns')
df9 = pd.crosstab(df['Gender: What gender do you identify with?'], df[Banner[8]], normalize= 'columns')
df10 = pd.crosstab(df['Gender: What gender do you identify with?'], df[Banner[9]], normalize= 'columns')
df11 = pd.crosstab(df['Gender: What gender do you identify with?'], df[Banner[10]], normalize= 'columns')
df12 = pd.crosstab(df['Gender: What gender do you identify with?'], df[Banner[11]], normalize= 'columns')
df13 = pd.crosstab(df['Gender: What gender do you identify with?'], df[Banner[12]], normalize= 'columns')
```

But when I try to run this as a loop I run into errors-

I have tried-

```
i = 0
while i < 10:
    df[i] = (pd.crosstab(df['Gender: What gender do you identify with?'], df[Banner[[i]]], normalize= 
'columns'))
    i = i+1
```

and receive error-

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-682256052209> in <module>
  1 i = 0
  2 while i < 10:
----> 3     df[i] = (pd.crosstab(df['Gender: What gender do you identify 
with?'], df[Banner[[i]]], normalize= 'columns'))
       4     i = i+1
```

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list

I have also tried-

```
for i in range(0, len(Banner)):
    df[i] = (pd.crosstab(df['Gender: What gender do you identify with?'], df[Banner[[i]]], normalize= 
'columns'))
    i = i+1
```

And receive same error-

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list

Just curious why I run into this error when using loops but not creating manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the problem

```py
df[Banner[[i]]]
```

You have an extra "[  ]" around i making it a list hence the error:

```py
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

Use this instead:

```py
df[Banner[i]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help